# MySQL query to sum 2 rows

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm not a specialist in MySQL and need some help with a query.

table (t_teams)

**team | group**

```
Germany | A
Russia | B
Danmark | A
Japan | C
```

.....

table (t_matches)

```
id | fk_team1 | fk_team2 | points_team1 | points_team2
1 | Germany | Russia | 3 | 0
2 | Danmark | Japan | 3 | 0
3 | Germany | Japan | 3 | 0
4 | Russia | Danmark | 1 | 1
```

**Foreign keys are:**
fk_team1
fk_team2

Now, I want to sum all points in t_matches for each team by a mysql query.
The final result should looks like

```
**team | points**
Germany | 6
Russia | 1
Danmark | 1
Japan | 0
```

I tried something like this, but it doesn't work :-(

```
SELECT 
t1.team,
SUM(t2.points_team1) + SUM(t2.points_team2) AS points
FROM t_teams t1, t_matches t2
WHERE (t1.team = t2.fk_team1) OR (t1.team = t2.fk_team2)
```

Would be great when someone can help me with this simple query.

Comment: why Danmark not 4?

Answer (score 2):

You need to unpivot the data and then aggregate the results:

```
select team, sum(points)
from ((select fk_team1 as team, points_team1 as points from t_teams t
      ) union all
      (select fk_team2 as team, points_team2 as points from t_teams t
      )
     ) t
group by team;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I will try at weekend and give you a feedback. Great 